# Python task starts when VSCode is closed after update

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I recently updated VSCode, I used the Insiders version on my M1 Macbook. After the stable Apple Silicon supported version of VSCode came out, I switched to it.

After that I noticed a strange behavior, whenever I close the App a Python task starts eating my CPU. (I checked that in Activity Monitor, and it used 80%) So I deinstalled it completely and removed any remaining files, and then reinstalled VSCode. And it still happens.

I don't know, if it's a bug, or just a wrong setting. If you know something I would appreciate some advice/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. That worked for me: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15586. Don't forget to restart the application after changing the settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I resolved the issue, and your answer also works great! But after tinkering a while i found out, that i had some leftover extension junk in some hidden folders i did not find at the first. Cleaning them up and reinstalling the whole app solved the issue also.